# HTML form with checkbox and number types submission with PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

For learning purposes, I'm doing this website where user can select some items and the number of units he wants, let's say it's this simplest shopping app.

So, I read from database the existing items in catalog:

```
$queryResult=$mySQL->query("SELECT nombre, precio, id FROM productos");
```

Then I print the list of products:

```
    $queryResult=$mySQL->query("SELECT nombre, precio, id_producto FROM productos");
    echo "<form action=\"checkout.php\" method=\"POST\">";
    while($datos=$mySQL->fetch_array($queryResult))
    {   
        $nombre=$datos['nombre'];
        $id_producto=$datos['id_producto'];
        $precio=$datos['precio'];

        echo "<h1>$nombre</h1>";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$id_producto\" value=\"on\"> Cantidad: <input type=\"number\" name=\"$id_producto"."Number\""." min=\"1\" max=\"20\" step=\"1\" value=\"1\"><br>";
        echo "<h3>Precio: $precio</h3><br>";

    }

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Comprar\">";
    echo "</form>";
```

They get as value the ones from `$id_producto`, in the case of the number type inputs I concatenate `"Number"` so they dont get the same name.

After submission, I'm trying to do something like:

```
foreach($_POST as $post_key => $post_value){     

    if ($post_value=="on") {
        $var1 = $_POST['.$post_key."Number".'];
    }
}
```

So if a checkbox was selected I check for its corresponding numeric value.

**Is it OK to perform another $_POST['somevariable'] inside that loop?**
**How can I concatenate that argument inside the square brackets?**

Comment: try replacing `$_POST['.$post_key."Number".']` to `$_POST[$post_key."Number"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes, that's for when the key is a constant string. Since your key is an expression, just put that expression inside the brackets:

```
if ($post_value=="on") {
    $var1 = $_POST[$post_key."Number"];
}
```

A better way to do this is to post the inputs as arrays:

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"producto[]\" value=\"$id_producto\"> Cantidad: <input type=\"number\" name=\"Number[$id_producto]\" min=\"1\" max=\"20\" step=\"1\" value=\"1\"><br>";
```

Then you can use the loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['producto'] as $post_value) {
    $var1 = $_POST['Number'][$post_value];
}
```

Comment: Why would the $_POST index would be from a matrix?

Comment: When you use `name="xxx[]"`, PHP collects all those inputs into an array in `$_POST['xxx']`.

Comment: So the `['Number']` part in `$var1 = $_POST['Number'][$post_value];` sentence is quite PHP-ish?

Comment: It comes from `<input type="number" name="Number[$id_producto]">`.

Comment: I get now! There will be simple ones like `$_POST['cat']` if I have any input with name cat, and in this case checks for the `$_POST['Number']`'s ones